# How to group financial time series objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, financial

I want to group 2 or more financial time series objects of different length.
Specifically, I have FTS a and b, a is shorter than b, and how can I get a time series c, so that c has two sub series a and b, and all the missing records in a is filled with null values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [MERGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/finance/merge.html) function is what you're looking for.